# factory_girls sequence and uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

I have this setup in the factories.rb.

```
Factory.sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@factory.com" }
Factory.sequence(:username) { |n| "username_#{n}" }

Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.email { Factory.next :email }
  u.username { Factory.next :username }
  u.first_name 'Ivan'
  u.last_name 'Pupkin'
  u.latitude '42'
  u.longitude '-71'
  u.password 'qwerty'
  u.password_confirmation 'qwerty'
end
```

When i creating two instances of the Factory(:users) i got uniqueness error.

```
describe CartsController do

  let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
  let(:another_user) { Factory(:user) }
  let(:cart) { Factory(:cart) }


  describe 'show my cart' do
    before { sign_in user}
    before { get :show, :id => user.carts.last }
    it { should respond_with :success }
  end

  describe 'show different person cart' do
    before { sign_in user }
    before { get :show, :id => another_user.carts.last}
    it { should respond_with :redirect }
  end
end
```

Where is my problem?

```
Failure/Error: let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
Validation failed: Username has already been taken, Email has already been taken
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there are records in your DB because fails `let(:user) { Factory(:user) }` and not `let(:another_user) { Factory(:user) }` so I see two possible solutions: add `User.delete_all` in the top or manually clean DB

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's leftovers in the test db. You should have the following line in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Note that this is useful even though you are using factories rather than fixtures. It wraps each example in a database transaction so that you have a clean slate every time. If you aren't using ActiveRecord, or if transactions are not going to work for you for any other reason, you need to pull in something like the `database_cleaner` gem to clean up the test database after each test run.